# HttpResponse Special Char "Zero Width Space"

Tags: c#, http, encoding

I have a problem regarding special chars encoding/decoding.

**Problem**

I have a Windows Service simply exposing an HTTP endpoint that returns a collection of objects as json (Content-Type: application/json;charset:utf-8). The data exposed is a list of objects related to one another. The name of some objects may have special chars in it, just as the ä ö and so on. But I came across another special char that is called "zero width space", which can be achieved by copying data from Microsoft Office OneNote in some certain circumstances.

"Lorem​Ipsum​Dolor​Sit​Amet" copy it into notepad and press left or right arrow to navigate within this string, you will notice that there is some char that is not visible  - the zero width space. (alternatively you can copy it into notepad++ and enable special chars to be shown)

But let's take a look what it looks like in my example.

The result looks like this in chrome (see picture 1)
[image: Picture 1]

*Picture 1: Result in Chrome*

---

The result looks like this in chrome when opened in developer console and edited as HTML (see picture 2)
[image: Picture 2]
*Picture 2: Result in Chrome Dev Console - Edit as HTML*

---

And the result deserialized with JavaScript Deserializer in C# (see picture 3)
[image]

*Picture 3: Result deserialized in C#*

---

Requesting the data from the service exposing the HTTP endpoint is as followed:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        EntityTagHeaderValue eTag = ETagStore.GetValue(URL);
        if (eTag != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(eTag.Tag))
            request.Headers.Set("If-None-Match", eTag.Tag);
        else
            request.Headers.Set("If-None-Match", null);

        try
        {
            var response = request.GetResponse();
            response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";


            var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            var reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

The result in database looks like Lorem?Ipsum?Dolor?Sit?Amet and the result I want it to be is: "LoremIpsumDolorSitAmet". 
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Fix your database, it isn't capable of storing Unicode.  Change the column type from, say, varchar to nvarchar.

Comment: Also note that there is no "charset" parameter on applocation/json.

Comment: Why don't you simply remove this symbol from result variable?

Comment: @HansPassant was right. I realized it a couple of minutes after I posted the question. Thanks.